# how to import modules without problems

Tags: python-3.x, module, python-import

after working with nodeJS require for awhile, Python3 module system is confusing me. After re-reading the tutorial https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

I have

```
app.py
config/
    __init__.py
    app_config.py
```

in `app.py` I have:

```
import config.app_config
```

ie `import FOLDER/FILE`

then I should be able to refer to variables/methods in that file by a fully-qualified name eg: `config.app_config.varname`

But my linter says `E0611 No name 'app_config' in module 'config'`

NB python3.6 I don't think the `__init__` files are needed anymore.

Update: to further confuse things, the above syntax is OK in some files but not ok in others - that are sitting at exactly the same point in the folder hierarchy. >.<; What is python doing wrong to me?

Answer (score 0):

OK i think this is because my linter was somehow using a different environment version of python. seems to work when executed. love/hate linters!